# A quick test shows big difference comparing EF core to ADO.Net

Tags: c#, ado.net, entity-framework-core

I am reading that the EF core performance is improved and is almost as fast as ADO.NET and decided to create a simple test. The results I got, show huge difference. ADO.NET was 10 times faster.

I am posting here the code I used to test. Is there something wrong with my test? 
Steps taken:

Reverse engineer a database using Scaffold-DbContext.
Get one record from one table:

```
using (var db = new TestFECore.Models.AchieveDB_EncryptContext())
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var disbursement = db.Disbursement
                         .Where(c => c.CashOutid > 999 && c.CashOutid < 2001)
                         .First();

    Console.WriteLine(disbursement.DisbursementId.ToString()); 

    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed:" + elapsedMs.ToString());

    var dis = new TestFECore.Models.Disbursement();
    var ds = new DataService();

    watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    dis = ds.GetDisbursements();

    Console.WriteLine("Cashoutid from regular ado.net " + dis.DisbursementId.ToString());
    watch.Stop();

    elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds; 
 }
```

Here is the GetDisbursements code

```
 public  Models.Disbursement GetDisbursements()
      //   public List<Models.Disbursement> GetDisbursements()
      {

         Models.Disbursement disbursement = new Models.Disbursement();
         using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=*******; etc"))
         {
            string commandString = @" The exact SQL created by the EF ";
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


            while (reader.Read())
            {

               disbursement.DisbursementId = (int)reader["DisbursementId"];

            }


            reader.Close();

         }
            return disbursement;
      }
```

Here are the results:

```
Core 3.0 Testing!
Querying Disbursments
1498
Time elapsed:2138
Using regular ado.net
Cashoutid from regular ado.net 1498
Time elapsed:144
Press enter to continue...
```

Where am I wrong in my comparison?
Thanks

Comment: "*Where am I wrong in my comparison*" Your testing methodology... In short performance testing is not a trivial thing, many factors can play a roll in the results. I.e first call to dbContext, connection caching, What you call first, whether you are in debug mode, whether the query plan was cached, what benchmarking framework you are using, how you are using it. In short we cant add anything to this even if these results are real, this is simple not a rigorous enough test. .

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order? also have you prewarmed these queries to make sure they are cached or vice versa, another useful thing is to run this multiple times and take an average, also using a legit testing framework would be a good start. The fact is there will be a difference, what they are with this query and your db, infrastructure ect remains to be seen with this level of diligence

Comment: *I am reading that the EF core performance is improved and is almost as fast as ADO.NET* not sure what you read, but I'm sure there's more details and qualified scopes and scenarios to it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting so fast. I know it is not trivial and I would ignore small difference to either but the difference was significant to ask the question. I did try to reverse the test and got a little different results 366 ms for ADO.NET and 1759 for FE. Also the watch started only after the using(var db = new TestFECore.Models.AchieveDB_EncryptContext()) .  I did not use any benchmark framework, just very simple console project based on EF core 3.0.

Comment: I mean.. I don't expect EF to be as fast as ADO.NET, but it could approach it.. EF is a framework for DataAccess infrastructure where ADO.NET is one provider of it, right?  At best, you're looking for EF to optimize it's usage of the ADO.NET provider and handle ExpressionTree transveral and generation.. If it is able to recognize an expression tree is the same as a ADO.NET cached query plan it can skip transveral and generation and just use the cached query plan..

Comment: anyhow... this question is quickly becoming a discussion board.. it unclear and too broad for this community to address I would think.

Answer (score 0):

Following the remarks of TheGenral "first call to dbContext", I added a query to another table before the comparison and now I am getting close enough results. Thanks